# What does a child function do in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference) for Firebase and I came to this part:

```
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
    // A post entry.
    var postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().**child('posts')**.push().key;
```

How am I supposed to understand this? Currently I'm thinking this is saying "from the root of the database, create a node and store its access key in a variable". What is the use of having a child function with 'posts'? I can run similar code like the following and get the same result.

```
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second bit of code does not really give the same result, when taken in the context of the rest of the code sample from the docs (that you didn't show here).

Actually, the code you've shown does not actually create any data in the database at all, because if nothing is passed to push(), then it just returns a reference to the location (with a unique key) that you can later write to.  The part of the sample that you omitted actually performs the update.

The API docs for [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child) says:

> Gets a Reference for the location at the specified relative path.

The method is helping you build a path to a reference.  Without the call to child() in your second example, the reference will be at the root of the database, rather than under "/posts".  While you will get a unique key in both situations, its location in the database will be different (after you actually write data there).

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I thought it would've been too long for others to read, but I guess I was wrong and put things out of context. Thanks, also I'll make note to read references next time.